# Get 2 graphs from the same column (dates) in 1 pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I have a constructed a pivot table, where a single column Field is filled with dates, and I would like to do a comparison between subsets of values in only this particular column.

So let's say Column C contains a range of dates from 1st of Jan to present date. I've grouped them (right-click the column in the pivot table -> Groups) so that it counts how many entries there are for each date rather than counting the total number of entries. For instance, having 5 entries for 01.01.15 now shows up as "1st Jan: 5"

What I now want to do is add a diagram based on this column, where it shows how many entries there are for a given month with one line, and another line where it shows the same data for a different month. The result should let the reader do a visual comparison of how many entries there are for a given date these 2 months.

The graph on this screenshot is hacked together using manually made intermediate tables, which isn't really what I want - I want to do it straight out of the table, because I would potentially want to do it for many different periods:

[image]

Can this be done the way my pivot table is setup now? Even better, can this be achieved for two arbitrarily defined timeperiods?

Comment: What do you mean "grouped"? And are you working with pivot tables or pivot charts? A screenshot of what you have vs what you want might be helpful.

Comment: Updated the question, I hope this is clearer.